# Mapping Address to unique number

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, ip-address, ipv4

What is the best way to make a unique number from the IP Address?

```
19.22.145.103
```

I was planning to sum each octet to get unique number but it looks like I might not get a unique number for each IP Address.

```
Sum of each octet 19 + 22 + 145 + 103 = 289 as the unique number.
```

I already know that we can't map IPv4 to 16 bit so solution with less collisions are acceptable. I am looking for both the solution as mentioned in below two points.

- Firstly what is the best way to get unique number by storing it in 32 bit datatype?
- Secondly now problem is I need to store this unique number in `short` data type. Since short is 16 bit so we might not be able to map IPv4 to short uniquely. Is there any other way we can come up which will have **less collisions** if we still use `short` datatype instead of using sum of each octet as I was using above?

All my IP Addresses starts with `10.` if helps in deciding the algorithm so there will be fewer collisions.

Comment: Kind of hard to store 32 bits in a 16 bit data type isn't it?

Comment: Yeah that's why I said any better way which can have less collisions.

Comment: The question could be more clear if you stated in the top of the question that you realize you can't map uniquely from 32 bits to 16 so collisions are acceptable.

Comment: @JohnDood just added now

Comment: Not only are collisions possible when mapping from 32 bits to 16 bits, they're highly likely. For every 16-bit number there are 2^16 possible collisions, regardless of how good your hashing algorithm is. Or, put another way, with a 16 bit hash code, your likelihood of collision is 50% after you've generated about 300 hash codes. At 1,000, it's probably close to 100% How many IP addresses are you planning on indexing this way?

Comment: I might have only max 1000 IP Addresses which I need to hash and get unique number. Knowing IP Address beforehand is not possible but for now I do know all those IP Addresses but if we add more machines in future then that Ip Address won't be under my control.

Comment: Are those 1,000 IP addresses all within some relatively small range? If you can guarantee a small number of subnetworks, your problem becomes much easier. For example if all of your IP addresses start with "10.", then the range you have to deal with is reduced from 2^32 to 2^24, meaning fewer collisions.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes all my IPv4 addresses will start with `10.` for sure so then what hashing or algo I should use for fewer collisions?

Comment: Again, it depends. Will the second octet always be from a limited set? That is, will you have `10.2.*.*` and `10.37.*.*`, but no others? The point I'm trying to make is that you need to take advantage of commonalities in your data. If the URLs will always start with `10.`, then don't even use that part in your hash code calculation. In doing so, you limit your possible collisions. The bigger issue is that you need to study and understand the math behind hash codes and collision probabilities, and look for ways to leverage your knowledge of the data to limit your collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Make hash function, then cut it to the size of *short*. For example :

> (or some other prime numbers)
>   ( 7 ^ 19 + 5 * 22 + 11 * 145 + 17 * 103 ) % size_of_short

Comment: Was about to say the same thing. The BSD Checksum hashing algorithm even has Java code in the article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_checksum

Comment: I haven't known that algorithm. I always used prime numbers, i sure will check that BSD checksum. Thank you :)

Comment: I didn't know about it either ;). I just googled 16 bit hash and two clicks later was at the article

Comment: My method is as flexible as you can take modulo whatever you would like to. Every coprime number with primes you would like to.

Comment: @Rjiuk can you provide an example how hash function will look like in Java?

Answer (score 1):

an IPv4 is 4 octets so you can get a unique mapping using something like

```
public static int asInt(byte[] addr) {
    return (addr[0] & 0xFF) | ((addr[1] & 0xFF) << 8)
          | ((addr[2] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((addr[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

or

```
public static int asInt(byte[] addr) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(addr).readInt();
}
```

This gives you 2<sup>32</sup> possible values.  If you want to map this to a 16-bit and make sure it's unique you need to store the mapping elsewhere e.g.

```
final Map<Integer, Short> mapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
int next = 0;

public short idFor(byte[] bytes) {
    Integer i = asInt(bytes);
    return mapping.computeIfAbsent(i, x -> next++);
}
```

On Java 7 you can do

```
public short idFor(byte[] bytes) {
    Integer i = asInt(bytes);
    synchronized(mapping) {
        Short s = mapping.get(i);
        if (s == null)
            mapping.put(i, s = next++);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Note, a 16-bit value can only have 65536 possible unique values.

If you want a simple hash you can use something like

```
public short hash(int n) {
    return (short) (n ^ (n >>> 16))
}
```

You can add an aggetate function like

```
public short hash(int n) {
    n *= 10191; // an odd prime of around 2^^16
    return (short) (n ^ (n >>> 16))
}
```

What is not ideal is that the top bits don't produce much randomness this way. You can use a 64-bit calculation instead.

```
public short hash(int n) {
    long n2 = n * 0x6d0f27bdL; 
    n2 ^= (n2 >>> 21) ^ (n2 >>> 42);
    return (short) (n ^ (n >>> 16) ^ (n >> 32));
}
```

Comment: I am still using Java 7. If you can edit your example with Java 7 then it will be of great help.

Comment: @user1950349 I have added an example for Java 7.

Comment: Thanks. what is `int n` in your last example? It is not the ip address correct? I have IP Address in String variable.

Comment: @user1950349 It is the result of `asInt(byte[])` above but it could be the hashCode() of the String (though this is unlikely to be as good)

Comment: And also, all my IPv4 addresses starts with `10.` so there will be fewer collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is **generally** impossible. So I'd look for shortcuts from the business domain.

Do you need to map **all** IP addresses? You can probably skip `127.*.*.*` and `192.168.*.*`. But this is not enough. You need to cut down to 16 bit, which is a friction of the full range: `1 / 2^16` ~ `1  / 64000`

Answer (score -1):

i have a new way.. check out the code, it gives assurance that  your code will be unique...

```
private static final int HASH_PRIME = 23;
public static short convertIP(String ip) {
    String res = "";
    for(String num: ip.split("\\.")) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(num);
        while(val>HASH_PRIME) {
            val = val / HASH_PRIME;
        }
        if(new Random().nextInt(10) <= 4) {
            res += convertChar(val);
        } else {
            res += val;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result = "+res); // the result could be anything like: T2264, 19WGE, TWGE, 1922G4, etc

    return (short) (res.hashCode() % Short.MAX_VALUE);
}

private static char convertChar(int num) {
    return (char)((num % 26) + 65);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convertIP("19.22.145.103"));
    // the short code for the same IP will be unique majorly.. i.e. 24311, 23784, 31968, 16079, 23767 .. etc
}
```

Comment: *it gives assurance that your code will be unique.* And how does it do that? There are 2^32 possible IP addresses. You're squeezing those 2^32 possibilities into 2^16 slots. By the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) that's plain not possible. There are 2^16 possible IP addresses for every 16-bit number. There's no way you can guarantee uniqueness. In addition, your use of `random` almost certainly guarantees that you won't get the same hash code when the IP addresses are equal. That's just wrong.

Comment: I believe the requirement was for getting short value for every IP. plz let me know how it could be possible to get same IP address. (as you said 2^32 possible IP). I know my code does not provide same short value for same IP, but that's the point.. you need to reduce the probability of collision.